# trouble to displaying json data on jqgrid and formatting

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem where I need to display json data on a jqgrid. The data I get is of the following format:

```
{"data":{"data":"\tat org.aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa(aaa.java:512)[147:org.aaa.aaa.aaa:9.1.1]\n\tat aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa(aaa.java:1789)[146:org.aaa:9.1.1]\n"}}
```

My javascript to display the data is:

```
 $("#grid").jqGrid({
  url: '/getdata',
      datatype: "json",
  mtype: "GET",
  colNames:['data'],
  colModel:[
     {name:'data', index:'data', align:'center'}
  ],
   jsonReader : {
          repeatitems: false,
      id: "0",
      cell: "",
       root: "logs",
      page: function() { return 1; },
      total: function() { return 1; },
      records: function(obj) { return obj.length; }
    },
   loadonce: true,      
   viewrecords: true,
   autowidth: true,
   multiselect: false,
   ignoreCase: true,
   sortable: true,
   height: 600, 
   rowNum: 999
 });
```

I tried a few combinations, but could not get the data to be displayed on the jqgrid with this code. The jqgrid displays an empty table. I guess I am missing something here.

I also have to format the data so that every time we hit '\n', we display it in a new row. I guess I can use 'addrowdata' in the formatter for the column to do that. Is that right?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Asha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use `addRowData`. It's more effectively to use `beforeProcessing` to modify the data returned from the server to the format which jqGrid can read. You can for example to split the `data.data` part by `\n` and fill the array of the corresponding items:

```js
autoencode: true,
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var items = data.data.data.split("\n"), i, l, item;
    data.logs = [];
    for (i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
        item = $.trim(items[i]);
        if (item.length > 0) {
            data.logs.push([item]);
        }
    }
}
```

I included the call of [jQuery.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) in the above code to remove unneeded `\t` or other white space characters at the beginning or at the end of every line.

I included additionally `autoencode: true` option which is strict recommended to be sure that the texts which included special characters for HTML (like `<`, `>`, `&` and so on) will be correctly displayed inside of the grid.

Additionally you should change `jsonReader` to for example the following

```
jsonReader: {
    root: "logs",
    cell: "",
    id: function () {
        return function () {
            return $.jgrid.randId();
        }
    },
    page: function() { return 1; },
    total: function() { return 1; },
    records: function(obj) { return obj.logs.length; }
}
```

The value of `id` seems tricky, but the implementation generate really unique values for `id` attribute of every line.

The corresponding demo you will find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Asha.htm).

Comment: Thanks Oleg, worked like a charm with a few changes. I had to make the changes because I missed a few things when I posted the data and I got the search/filtering free. One question though, is there any way to add a filter icon next to the search text box. Thanks again.